# Wireshark lua dissector unable to load for media_type=application/octet-stream

Tags: lua, wireshark, media-type

I'm trying to write a lua Proto to parse our private protocol on http. But Wireshark didn't enter my dissector function when the media_type  to "application/octet-stream". When the media_type is set to "text/html", everything looks fine. 
   Is there special handling for application/octet-stream?
   I was working on it for almost a day, Could you help me out? 
   Thx a lot

My wireshark version is 1.10.2 on mac osx 10.8.5

Here's my code

```
do
    local myproto= Proto("myprotoProtocol","myproto Protocol")
    local f_version= ProtoField.uint32("Version","Version",base.DEC)
    myproto.fields = {f_version}
    local data_dis = Dissector.get("data")
    local function myproto_dissector(tvb,pkt,root)
            print("enter myproto_dissector, tvb.len:"..tostring(tvb:len()))
            if tvb:len() < 17 then return false end
            pkt.cols.protocol = "myproto"
            local t =root:add(myproto,tvb)
            t:add(f_version,tvb(0,2))
            local version = tvb(0,2).uint()
            print("version:"..tostring(version))
            return true
    end

    function myproto.dissector(tvb,pkt,root)
            print("enter myproto.dissector")
            if not myproto_dissector(tvb,pkt,root) then
                    data_dis:call(tvb,pkt,root)
            end
    end

    local tbl= DissectorTable.get("media_type")
    tbl:add("application/octet-stream",myproto)
    --tbl:add("text/html",myproto) --text/html looks fine
    print("adding myproto into DissectorTable")
 end
```

I use tshark to debugging
   for application/octet-stream

```
$tshark  -r test.pcapng   |grep application/octet-stream
108 40.536817000    10.8.0.14 -> 10.130.142.72 HTTP 418 POST /protocol?uid=101225&uid=101225&_t=1382115502 HTTP/1.1  (application/octet-stream)
111 40.596037000 10.130.142.72 -> 10.8.0.14    HTTP 63 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (application/octet-stream)
120 40.657143000    10.8.0.14 -> 10.130.142.72 HTTP 445 POST /protocol?uid=101225&uid=101225&_t=1382115502    HTTP/1.1  (application/octet-stream)
124 40.729645000 10.130.142.72 -> 10.8.0.14    HTTP 63 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (application/octet-stream)
219 41.810493000    10.8.0.14 -> 10.130.142.72 HTTP 488 POST /protocol?uid=101225&uid=101225&_t=1382115503 HTTP/1.1  (application/octet-stream)
226 41.919401000 10.130.142.72 -> 10.8.0.14    HTTP 63 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (application/octet-stream)

$tshark  -r test.pcapng   -X lua_script:canon.lua | grep myproto
adding myproto into DissectorTable
```

for text/html

```
 $tshark  -r test.pcapng   -X lua_script:canon.lua | grep myproto
 adding myproto into DissectorTable
 enter myproto.dissector
 enter myproto_dissector, tvb.len:2
 enter myproto.dissector
 enter myproto_dissector, tvb.len:6
 enter myproto.dissector
 enter myproto_dissector, tvb.len:6
```

Perhaps it might be the bug of wireshark when the media_type is not list in the dissector table.   'application/octet-stream' is not listed on the table yet.
After I use Lua->evaluate in Wireshark, The dissector table shows my protocol like this, 'application/octet-stream' is in mess code.

When i use 'print(tbl:get_dissector("application/octet-stream"))' in tshark, it shows "MYPROTO". Looks the correct one.

Comment: I think i found the problem after I modified the source code "wslua_proto.c" line 1722 - comment "g_free(pattern);". Because the sub_dissectors->hash_table just add the pattern as point without duplicate a copy in "packet.c".

Comment: The bug seems to be introduced since v1.8, 1.6 looks fine. http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/viewvc/trunk-1.6/epan/wslua/wslua_proto.c?revision=39927&view=markup

Comment: In the trunk, 1.10, and 1.8 versions, the pattern *is* duplicated (see the statement in `dissector_add_string()` after the `/* do the table insertion */` comment; it calls `g_strdup()` for the second argument to the `g_hash_table_insert()` call).

Answer (score 0):

Please submit a bug to Wireshark, at [bugs.wireshark.org](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla), either with or without your code changes, but preferably with a sample capture file showing the problem (even if it's only one or two packets that's fine).

(I would have made this a comment but I don't have enough points to do that apparently)